# Pine Script: How to be able to manually input values for specific dates

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to create an indicator where I can manually input values for specified dates.

For example, I want a value of 40 to be shown on the indicator on 12/1/2021, a value of 80 on 12/2/2021 and a value of 90 on 12/3/2021, and so forth.

I'm new to all this, but maybe describing the time in Pine Script for one of those dates would look like this (?):

```
if timestamp(2021, 12, 1, 0, 0) == close
```

I really don't know... is this even a possible task? I'm sure it is, but I have no idea how to figure this out. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use input.time() to manually input timestamps.

[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input{dot}time](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_input%7Bdot%7Dtime)

```
//@version=5
indicator("time input", overlay = false)

ts1 = input.time(timestamp("Dec 1 2021 00:00 +000"), title = "Timestamp 1")
ts2 = input.time(timestamp("Dec 2 2021 00:00 +000"), title = "Timestamp 2")
ts3 = input.time(timestamp("Dec 3 2021 00:00 +000"), title = "Timestamp 3")

float val = na

if time == ts1
    val := 40

if time == ts2
    val := 80

if time == ts3
    val := 90

plot(val)
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough for helping me! But, it seems like the indicator is not working. The indicator pane is able to be displayed on the chart, but it is simply empty. When I click on the values of the specified dates, the values appear selected, but I can't see the values otherwise. What do you think seems to be the solution for this?